# XMLRPC problem with a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access an XMLRPC API (for the Magento PHP app) from my Rails application.
I'm using a gem however whenever I try to connect on my local machine (Snow Leopard) I get this error:

no such file to load -- xmlrpc

This is triggered by a line require 'xmlrpc'

Is there a specific Ruby XMLRPC gem I need to install?

Sorry for the stupid question...

Answer (score 1):

There is no xmlrpc.rb file, you should write

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'
```